# Custom user model: Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive

Tags: django, django-models, django-custom-user

I always get the message **"Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."** I write in settings.py AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'eCommerce.User'.
And after I run makemigrations and migrate command I use these commands: python manage.py createsuperuser and then python manage.py runserver.
There is no errors in cmd but in the Django administration the above message shows.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,name,password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must enter an email address.")
        if not name:
            raise ValueError("Users must enter a name.")

        user = self.model(
                email= self.normalize_email(email),
                name= name,
                #phone_number = phone_number,
               
            )
        user.set_password=password
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email,name,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                name= name,
                email= self.normalize_email(email),
                password= password
            )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using= self._db)
        return user



class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=50, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True 
                                        ,related_name='billing_address')
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
                                         related_name='shipping_address')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']
    objects = UserManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return "Email: " + str(self.email) + "Name: " + str(self.name)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Comment: `user.set_password=password` do you see the problem here?

Comment: Thank youuu!! I don't know how I couldn't see that for hours !

Answer (score 0):

```html
add this under your user model

@property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
       
        return self.is_staff

or simply write it as 

@property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```